# JavaFX node partially transparency

Tags: java, events, javafx, transparency

I'm working on a drawing application. In short, this application consists of a background node (a white rectangle) that handles drawing (via mousepressed, mousedragged, mousereleased events). The nodes that get drawn in this way are on top of the background node.

Now, every drawn node has a contextmenu. I want to have the drawn nodes consume a mouse event only when it is a mousepressed event of the MouseButton.SECONDARY type... Otherwise, the event should be propagated to the background node.

Currently, I can open the drawn nodes contextmenu but I can't draw another node on top of this drawn node because the event is not propagated to the background node...

How should I go about this?

//edit

Currently I'm using a workaround:

```
EventHandler< MouseEvent > handler = new EventHandler< MouseEvent > ( ) {
        @Override
        public void handle ( MouseEvent event ) {
            if ( event.getEventType ( ) == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED
                    && event.getButton ( ) == MouseButton.SECONDARY ) {
                showContextMenu ( event.getScreenX ( ), event.getScreenY ( ) );
            } else {
                Background.getInstance ( ).fireEvent ( event );
            }
        }
    };
setOnMousePressed ( handler );
setOnMouseDragged ( handler );
setOnMouseReleased ( handler );
```

I suppose there should be a better method...